# PHP For Each Download File

Tags: php, javascript, foreach

I'm either using incorrect syntax or going about this with the wrong method.

In the html document that references this php file, there is a simple list of checkboxes. The user checkmarks the boxes and hits submit. This then kicks off with the goal of prompting the user to run or save each file. If I checkmark test1.txt, test2.txt and test3.txt, there should be a popup for each (assuming of course the browser is IE).

The issue is that only the 'last' checkmarked item is downloaded - the rest are not. I thought of opening a popup window for each file found but it has no effect. If I use echo $filename, it then correctly displays each entry I checkmarked so the php script appears to be given the multiple file names correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm pretty sure the $filename in the window.open parameter is not being used in the right syntax right now too.

Here is the script:

```
<?php

foreach($_POST['files'] as $filename) {

echo "<SCRIPT language=\"JavaScript1.2\">function openwindow() {window.open ('$filename', 'execute','location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=500,height=500');}</script><body onload=\"openwindow()\"></body>";

  }

?>
```

Comment: You're just repeatedly overwriting the `openwindow()` function with a new definition. You're also not going to be able to have multiple `<body>` elements.

Comment: would fopen() be a better choice? I tried it and kept getting permission errors. The directory for testing purposes was set to 777 and the fopen options in the php ini file were set to ON (enable). There has got to be a better way of doing this than with javascript right?

Comment: Uh, `fopen` and `window.open` do massively different things. `fopen` won't do anything on the user's browser. It's server-side

Comment: Try changing the name of the window (i.e. `'execute'`) on each loop iteration. If you keep the same window name, it references the same window.

Comment: okay for client side, whats a better approach to redirecting to or opening a file in a web browser?

Comment: Then again, I've never seen a webpage able to initiate a download of more than one file at a time. Seems like something a browser would prevent from happening. Perhaps a better solution would be to zip the files and download the zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openwindow(filename) {window.open (filename, 'execute','location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=500,height=500');}

<?php
foreach($_POST['files'] as $filename) {

echo "openwindow('".$filename."');";

}
?>

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: `<SCRIPT language=\"JavaScript1.2\">` can be replaced with `<script>`.

Comment: The code you supplied appears to work, however, it only seems to open the last checked item. For instance, if I check test1.txt and test2.txt, which are in the same directory, it only popups a window for the test2.txt - test1.txt appears to be ignored or its launch command is 'overwritten' for lack of a better term

Comment: Disregard previous comment - it works after restarting chrome and IE - probably something with cache. Thank you for your effort!